# How do you convert multiple lines of String input to Upper Case until EOF?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        String str2 = "";

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
            str1 = keyboard.nextLine();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
            output.append(sb.toUpperCase().toString()).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.print(output.toString());
    }
}
```

I am looking to convert multiple lines of input until the EOF (ctrl+d) to Uppercase. What can be used to print out the same multiple lines all in Uppercase? For example, input and output would look like:

```
car
bus
taxi
CAR
BUS
TAXI
```

with the repeated lines in Uppercase.

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: Simple, write them in upper case.

Comment: This code is not ideal but it should work. What's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: he only want to uppercase the string only and if only the line were a repetition of previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Put the each line to Hashmap, and each time you get the line check if the same string found in the hashmap. If not, just print as normal and add to the hashmap. Otherwise print as uppercase.

Code should be look similar to this.

```
Map<String> lines = new HashMap();
while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
        str1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
        if(lines.get(str1)==null){
           // not found, put to hashmap and print normally.
           lines.put(str1);
           output.append(sb.toString().append("\n");
        }else{
           // found, so this line is repetitive, print the uppercase version. 
           output.append(sb.toUpperCase().toString()).append("\n");
        }   
}
```